How to compute the integral $\int_{0} ^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n!}\,dx$?
$$\int_{0} ^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n!}\,dx$$
I know that the sum definitely converges, and WolframAlpha gives the function
$$\sin(\sin(x))e^{\cos(x)}$$
for the closed form of the sum.
I have no idea how I can get to here, though. I have tried moving in the $\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}$ into the sum, and using a product-to-sum formula, and moving the sum outside the integral but that got me nowhere. I have also tried to expand out the series in an attempt to find a pattern that looks familiar, which also ended with nothing. Maybe my knowledge of math is just insufficient, but I am really quite lost here. I've mainly tried to simplify the integrand, haven't tried any actual integration yet.
Thanks in advance.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Does this make sense? $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sin (nx)}}{{n!}}}  = {\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{\rm e}^{{\rm i}nx} }}{{n!}}} } \right) = {\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} (\exp ({\rm e}^{{\rm i}x} )) = {\rm e}^{\cos x} \sin (\sin x)
$$

That does make sense. Thank you. Now that you've pointed out, it's quite obvious, really. I knew that the factorial in the denominator would have something to do with e but didn't think about taking the imaginary parts of euler's formula. How do you think I could simplify the integrand more? Can't see a nice way to integrate this without further simplification.
Also, thank you for the advice on making a post. It's my first time asking a question here so I am quite inexperienced.

Using $$\sin (x)\sin (nx)=\frac12\Big(\cos(n-1)x-\cos(n+1)x\Big)$$ and integrating by parts
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)\sin(nx)}{x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{(n+1)\sin(n+1)x-(n-1)\sin(n-1)x}{2x}dx=\frac\pi4\left(n+1-(n-1)\right)$$

More generally, for any function that has a Maclaurin series that converges absolutely on the unit circle, we have $$\frac{1}{2i} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^{2}} \left(f(e^{ix})-f(e^{-ix}) \right) , \mathrm dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \left(f(1)-f(0) \right). $$  The function here is $f(z) = e^{z}$.

The following is a generalization.
Let $f(z)$ be any function that has a Maclaurin series expansion that has a radius of convergence greater than $1$.
Then for $a>0$ we have
$ \begin{align} \frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{2}+a^{2}} \left(f(e^{ix})-f(e^{-ix}) \right) \, \mathrm dx &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{2}+a^{2}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \sin(nx) \, \mathrm dx \\  &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{2}+a^{2}} \sum_{n=\color{red}{1}}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \sin(nx) \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)\sin(nx)}{x^{2}+a^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \\  &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos\left((n-1)x\right)- \cos \left((n+1)x \right)}{x^{2}+a^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \\ &\overset{\spadesuit}{=} \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \left(\frac{\pi}{2a}e^{-(n-1)a}-\frac{\pi}{2a}e^{-(n+1)a} \right) \\ &= \frac{\pi}{4a} \left(e^{a}-e^{-a} \right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}e^{-na}  \\ &= \frac{\pi \sinh (a)}{2a} \left(f(e^{-a})-f(0) \right). \end{align}$
Taking the limit as $a \to 0^{+}$, we get $$\begin{align} \frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{2}} \left(f(e^{ix})-f(e^{-ix}) \right) \, \mathrm dx &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (x)}{x^{2}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \sin(nx) \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2} \left(f(1)-f(0) \right). \end{align}$$
Your integral is the case $f(z) = e^{z}$.

$\spadesuit$ Calculating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}\, \mathrm{d}x$ without using complex analysis

For a particular function and a particular value of $a$, Wolfram Alpha either returns a lousy approximation or needs more computation time.
To get an approximation that is correct to at least a few digits after the decimal point,  make the upper limit somewhat large, and tell Wolfram Alpha to use the midpoint method with as many intervals that it can handle without timing out.
For example, see here and here.

$\displaystyle +1$.  You just found a quasi-Lobachevsky Integral Formula.

@FelixMarin  It kind of does look similar.
